# How to find the date I joined Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page

How can I find the exact date that I joined Stack Overflow?

There is a *member for* section on my profile tab which shows that I have been a member for 2 years, 4 months, but I want to know the exact date when I joined.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just mouse-over that relative time string, it'll give you the ISO8601 date:

[image]

This trick should work for *any* relative time string you find on the site.

Answer (score 14):

Just run a SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854521?UserId=5740382)

```sql
select creationdate
from users
where id = ##userid:int?1##
```

Remember SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday so this won't work for very recent accounts.

Just call the SE API [/users/{id}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=5740382&filter=!23IYXArVHr59L7CFi9wSi&site=stackoverflow&run=true) endpoint:

```js
$('button').click(()=> $.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/'+ $('input').val()+'?site=stackoverflow&filter=!23IYXArVHr59L7CFi9wSi',(data)=>$('span').text(new Date(data.items[0].creation_date*1000))));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
User id:<input type='text' >
<br>
<button>Go</button>
<br>
<span></span>
```

Be aware of the [throttling rules](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) of the API. This snippet doesn't take any of them into account, nor does it handle error conditions. That is all left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: How to overcomplicate something using SEDE 101 :P

Comment: There is no rule that forbids overcomplicating things.

Comment: @AndréKool It's actually a 400-level course taught at the local university. CS 428: Complicated SEDE Queries for Already Easy Tasks

Comment: It needs more regex.

Comment: @DavyM how many credits is that course worth?

Comment: @Luuklag I don't know, they wrote the number of credits as the result of a complicated SEDE query.

Comment: Perfect..!!!!!!!!